# How to get a list of installed applications that can play a youtube video?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios6, youtube

How to get a list of installed applications that can play a youtube video? I need to show that list to the user. Can I use UIDocumentInteractionController?

Comment: What do you mean by "that can play a youtube video"? Every app can play a YouTube-video by embedding a `UIWebView` or an `MPMediaPlayerController`...

Comment: You don't use `UIDocumentInteractionController` you use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:]` What url I'm not sure as Youtube is no longer built in.

Comment: I have tried it using UIWebView, but I didn't like the way it opens the youtube video. So I thought I will display the apps list to user, where in he will select whatever app he likes to play that video.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. Youtube video's are not a file type.

Comment: Okay. Then same as UIDocumentInteractionController how can I get the list of apps that will open a video link?

Comment: You cannot.  You cannot know anything about other apps on iOS.  You can only use "canOpenURL" to know if someone could handle a particular URL (e.g. CoolApp://do-a-jiggy-wiggy).  Bummer - but I really think this is a lost cause.  It's tough and hacky to even get a list of other apps on the device, much less maintain a list of their capabilities (which you'd need to do on you own on the server-side).